# Hearth Stone: Tavern Brawl balanced?

Tags: hearthstone

Hearthstone has recently introduced Tavern Brawl mode that seems massively unbalanced. Is this the case or is that people have not had much experience playing it?

I have noticed that around  1 in 3 matches where I am the dragon, my opponent concedes.

Comment: This is not opinion based. It is about balance of the game type.

Comment: Balance is not measurable.

Comment: @wat not in simple terms , but it is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_(game_design)

Comment: I am a game designer, I know what balance means. However, it is near impossible to prove balance in a card game, unless a card is inherently better (as in better in every way imaginable) than another.

Comment: Even if this is not an opinion-based question, we've only yet seen one type of tavern brawl (with two bad guy 'heroes'). So either the question is too broad (are all these brawls unbalanced), or ill-worded (if you are only talking about this one week's brawl), or the answer constantly changes depending on whatever is in tavern brawl, or irrelevant to future readers. Take your pick!

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty unbalanced, but it is not such a big deal that it is unbalanced. Since a new Tavern Brawl will come out every week, And the fact that it is not a competitive game-mode it is more just for the fun.

Comment: I did enjoy the first few matches,  I'm just disappointed that its gets old pretty quick.

Comment: That is why a new one comes out every week, to keep it fresh. And it is not that hard for the developers to make since they don't have to test and balance so much. Most of their time while releasing new cards is spend on the testing and balancing.

Comment: From my understanding it's not horribly unbalanced, but Nefarian has a very strong early game and Ragnaros has a stronger late game. So as Nefarian you want to end it quickly (which you usually can) and as Rag you want to draw it out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Most of the games Nefarian has already killed Ragnaros before or just after the start of the late game.

Comment: I think I've win twice with Ragnaros . Both with a little luck.

Comment: The key to winning with Ragnaros is using the hero power as often as possible. You get a 5/1 token that doesn't cost you a card so you'll have a huge card advantage when/if you survive the early game.

Comment: It's not that unbalanced, people are just utterly terrible at playing Ragnaros.

Answer (score 4):

It's not balanced, but that's kind of the point.

When you play as Ragnaros, you are perceived to have a disadvantage. If you lose while playing as Ragnaros, it's okay! You were supposed to because of how good Nefarian is. If you win, you overcame the obstacle of randomness with Nefarian's hero power and a weaker deck.

The other side of the coin works too! When I get Nefarian, I know I'm supposed to win.

It's a fun, casual mode that lets you play with decks that break the mold of regular Hearthstone.